# Shortcut of end the call

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, calls

This might seem a foolish question but I'm facing this basic issue on my Samsung Galaxy Y Duos (android 2.3.6). This is my first Androide device and using it only since a week and a basic issue is ruining my Android experience.

While on call, if I press home button by mistake (Habit of last mobile), call minimize to top bar. This is specially painful when I need to cancel the call in urgency and I found call is minimized to taskbar, which then take considerable time to open the call and end it.

**Is there any way to end the call immediately (shortcut) or at the least prevent the call to minimize during call.**

Most basic and primary purpose of phone is to make/receive calls. I'm sure android must have taken care of that but its frustrating for me not to find that basic function.

Comment: There is a setting under Accessibility which allows you to end calls by using the power button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your phone settings menu. Under `Accessibility`, click the checkbox for `Power button ends call`.

Be careful using this with bluetooth. I have accidentally ended calls because I wanted to put the phone in my pocket; I pressed the power button (don't want my touchscreen active: I might accidentally end the call!), and the call ended.

Answer (score -2):

[Power Key End Call](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mhotspot.power) will let you end a call by pressing the power key. This should solve your problem; you can press the power key on any screen and end the current call.

Comment: That's not very helpful. How about a name? _How/why_ does it solve the problem?